# How to find EJS tags variable name from String?

Tags: javascript, regex, ejs

I have [EJS](https://ejs.co/) String and I am trying to get **EJS** tag variable names in an object: `{name: 1, car: 1}` because I need to project only those values from database which are present in the string.

**Example :**

```
let str = "His name is <%= name %> and he has <%= car[0].color %> car. <%= name %> is working in XYZ";
    str = str.split(' ');

    let project = {};
    str.forEach((text, index) =>{
        if(text === '<%='){
            project[str[index + 1].split('[')[0]] = 1;
        }
    });

    console.log(project) // {name: 1, car: 1}
```

Is there any better way of achieving the same or by using RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to do it with regex

```
var pattern = "<%=\s[a-zA-Z]+"; // will also find the '<%= ' at the beginning, will be cut out later
var str = "His name is <%= name %> and he has <%= car[0].color %> car. <%= name %> is working in XYZ";
var found = str.match(pattern); // get all matches

let project = {};
found.forEach((text, index) =>{
    found[index] = found[index].substring(4); // to cut out '<%= '
    project[found[index]] = 1; // add it to the array
});

console.log(project);
```

Comment: I tried @SomeCoder code's in Chrome console and found **project** value as null. Basically did copy & paste.

**I ended up with :**  




`let pattern = /<%=\s[a-zA-Z]+/g; 
  let str = "His name is <%= name %> and he has <%= car[0].color %> car. <%= age %> is working in XYZ";
  let found = str.match(pattern); 
  let project = {};
  found.forEach((text, index) =>{
   found[index] = found[index].substring(4); 
   project[found[index]] = 1;
  });

  console.log(project);`  



and got the output : {name: 1, car: 1}